# Chrome Extension chrome.downloads.download working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an extension that has a button to download a file.
The file is created with the contents retrieved from the chrome's localStorage.

In panel.html I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="btnDownload">Download</button>

    <script src="messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="panel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Panel.js** has the following event listener:

```
 document.querySelector('#btnDownload').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        sendObjectToInspectedPage({action: "download"}); 
    });
```

sendObjectToInspectedPage function is in **messaging.js**:

```
function sendObjectToInspectedPage(message) {
    message.tabId = chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId;
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(message);
}
```

On my **background.js** file I have the following code:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {

    var extensionListener = function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

        if(message.tabId && message.content) {           
               if(message.action  === 'download') {

                    var aFilePart = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">Hi :) !</b></a>'];
                    var blob = new Blob(aFilePart, {type : 'text/html'});
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    chrome.downloads.download({
                    url: url 
                    });

                //Pass message to inspectedPage
                } else {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.tabId, message, sendResponse);
                }

        // This accepts messages from the inspectedPage and 
        // sends them to the panel
        } else {
            port.postMessage(message);
        }
        sendResponse(message);
    }

    // Listens to messages sent from the panel
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(extensionListener);

    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function(port) {
        chrome.extension.onMessage.removeListener(extensionListener);
    });

});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    return true;
});
```

I want to generate the file with the content I pass and download the file to my computer when the download button is clicked but this is not working.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'runtime' to send the message in messaging.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
```

Also, in your background script this isn't required,

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener()
```

Here is a simple example

```
function popupMsg(message) {
    if (message.action == "download") {
        //Do Something
    } else {
        //Something else
    } 
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(popupMsg);
```

Here is the runtime documentation https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime